# Geometry problem from IMO Past Papers.

Tags: geometry, triangles

Each side of square ABCD is 2 unit in length. P is a point on BD such that
$\angle BCP = 30^{\circ}$. Area of triangle DCP can be expressed as $a-\sqrt{a}$ . Then, a= ?

Comment: You need to know about the ratios of legs and hypotenuse of 30-60-90 right triangles.  While these ratios are the cornerstone of trigonometry, for this special triangle they can be found by purely non-trigonometric means.

Comment: What is that "other than by trigonometry"?! Hey, this is a triangle, what do you think "trigonometry" means, if not "measuring three angles"? Besides, the problem is way too simple for IMO, must be another origin.

Comment: Can you help me out? I am preparing for my national olympiad. It would be very helpful. @DougM

Comment: Out of curiosity, which year was this on the IMO?

Comment: This is from BDMO 2017. National level olympiad in our country and its held across the country. People doing well will be selected for the IMO team which our country will send as the country's representative.

Comment: I wish you good luck.

Comment: @user8734617 I don't, sorry. If somebody can't solve such a simple problem, their place is not in an IMO team. IMO problems are much harder, you need participants who can do more for the honour of their country.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Although I don't share the tone of your comment at all (I still wish the OP good luck, regardless!), I do share your concern. IMO is tough.

Comment: @user8734617 I'm not sure what you didn't like in the tone (truth? worry about the honour of their country?), but IMO problems *are* simply another league than that. I've been there, twice, I know.

Comment: Chill guys. In our national olympiad the whole competition is divided into 4 categories. (Junior for class 3-5, Primary for 6-8, Higher 8-10, Higher Secondary 10+). People doing well in Junior, Primary, Higher will be awarded for doing well but only People from Higher Secondary will be selected to represent the country in IMO. People from Higher Secondary will only go to IMO. And I am just in Primary. Its just a preparing stage nothing else. Sorry if I caused a nuisance or annoyance among you. @user8734617

Comment: @ProfessorVector thanks anyway brother.

Comment: @Raad Shahmat You're welcome. BTW, how do you know about "brother"? According to the Harry Potter books, Professor Septima Vector is a woman. Well, I guess that's just poetical license, because I'm not. ;-)

Comment: @RaadShahmat Not at all, and thanks for the additional info. I can see the guys from your country are doing better every year (https://www.imo-official.org/country_team_r.aspx?code=BGD). Work hard and keep your spirits high! All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the height $PQ$ from $P$ onto $CD$. Let $x=DQ=QP$, then $QC=\frac{x}{\sqrt 3}$ and so we have (from $CD=DQ+QC$: $2=x(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt 3})$, i.e.

$$x=\frac{2}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}}=3-\sqrt 3$$

Because the area of $\triangle DCP$ is $\frac{1}{2}DC\cdot PQ=x$, we have the area equal to $3-\sqrt 3$. This would mean $a=3$.

It is possibly needed to check if there is another solution for $a$: if $a-\sqrt a=3-\sqrt 3$, then $(\sqrt a-\sqrt 3)(\sqrt a + \sqrt 3) = a-3=\sqrt a - \sqrt 3$, i.e. $(\sqrt a-\sqrt 3)(\sqrt a+\sqrt 3-1)=0$. As the second factor is $\gt 0$, the first factor must be $0$, i.e. $\sqrt a=\sqrt 3$, implying $a=3$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Without trig...

CPQ is an equilateral triangle.

M is the midpoint of PQ

$b = \frac 12 c\\
a^2 + b^2 = c^2\\
a = b\sqrt 3\\
a+b = 2$

the area of $DCP = a$

$a (1 + \frac {\sqrt 3}{3}) = 2\\
a = \frac {6}{3 + \sqrt 3}\\
a = DCP =  3-\sqrt 3$

I am using $a$ differently than you used $a$ in the Original Post.  I hope that isn't too confusing.

Comment: How can you be sure that M is the Midpoint? @DougM

Comment: I defined it to be the midpoint.  I will leave it for you to prove that $MCP$ is, in fact, $30^\circ.$  It is not hard.